# Родительный или винительный падеж? (1)

Tags: падежи, родительный-или-винительный

Какое из предложений является грамматически верным:
"**Я никогда не изучал английский язык**" или "**Я никогда не изучал английского языка**"?

Answer (score 3):

Речь идет, конечно, об отрицательных конструкциях с существительными в винительном и родительном падежах. Почему-то в учебниках по РКИ этот момент прекрасно разъяснен, а вот для своих - ищи свищи. В связи с тем, что подобные вопросы не единичны, считаю нужным привести пространное пояснение по данной теме.

При переходных глаголах с отрицательной частицей НЕ могут употребляться существительные в винительном и родительном падежах, которые часто выступают как синонимы.

**Винительный падеж обязателен:**
1) в конструкциях с частичным отрицанием: *Он не читает, а просматривает газеты;*
2) в конструкциях со сложным предикатом: *я не смог купить тетрадь; он не успел найти решение; он не считал это занятие полезным;*
3) в устойчивых фразеологических словосочетаниях: *не морочь мне голову; не заговаривай мне зубы*.

**Винительный падеж предпочтительнее:**
1) у существительных обозначающих определенный конкретный предмет: Я *не купил книгу (о которой ты мне говорил); Не потеряй билет на поезд*;
2) у одушевленных предметов и имен собственных: *Я не видел тетю три года; Он не любит Москву*;
3) при наличии слов **некому, негде, не к чему**: *не к чему приложить силы; негде опубликовать работу*;
4) при наличии частиц с отрицанием **едва не, чуть не**: *едва не уронил вазу, чуть не разбил тарелку*.

**Родительный падеж обязателен**:
1) в устойчивых словосочетаниях: *не играть роли, не обращать внимания, не придавать значения*;
2) в сочетании с глаголом ***не иметь***: *не иметь значения (влияния, смысла, возможности, денег, машины)*;
3) при наличии слов *никакой, ничей*, а также частицы **НИ**: *не получил никакого подарка; не послал ни письма, ни открытки;*
4) в устойчивых фразеологических сочетаниях: *не сводить глаз* (с кого?); *не находить себе места; не сказать худого слова*.

**Родительный падеж чаще употребляется**:
1) у отвлеченных и абстрактных существительных: *не причинить беспокойства (боли); не уронить достоинства; не вынести трудностей;*
2) в сочетании с глаголами чувственного и мысленного восприятия **не видеть, не слышать, не чувствовать, не замечать, не понимать, не знать, не помнить и драгими**: *не помнить адреса; не замечать успеха*.

Что касается фразы "Я никогда не изучал английский язык (английского языка)", то здесь каких-то однозначных рекомендаций нет. Следовательно, оба варианта возможны.

Comment: Расшифруйте, пожалуйста, РКИ

Comment: Русский как иностранный.

Answer (score 1):

Есть случаи, когда предпочтительнее родительный падеж, есть - когда винительный (Много подобных примеров описано в "Словаре грамматических вариантов русского языка", РАН, 2007 год). Данный случай относится к тем, когда допустимы оба варианта.

Answer (score 1):

В нейтральной, эмоционально не окрашенной речи: "не изучал английского языка".

Но в тысячный раз: собака зарыта в контексте.
Сравните: "Нужен человек, знающий английский язык" - "Но я никогда не изучал английский язык!" (именно английский, я с рождению на нём разговариваю, и ещё на китайском, суахили и кечуа). 
"Я никода не изучал английского языка... французского тоже..." (только русский устный и русский письменный со словарём).
Иногда и письменный контекст не даёт ответа, тогда выбором формы автор может передать стилистическую окраску или особенность речи героя.

Answer (score 0):

Не изучал: кого-что? Значит - "английский язык".

Answer (score 0):

Есть правило: *знаю (что?)* и *не знаю (чего?)*, но, думаю, оно не относится к слову "изучал", поэтому правильным является первый вариант:  *"Я никогда не изучал английский язык"*.

Answer (score 0):

Правильно: **Я *никогда* не изучал английского языка.**

**При усилении отрицания** используется Р.п.

Розенталь: [http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/66.htm#з_04](http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/66.htm#%D0%B7_04)

Родительный падеж, имеющий в рассматриваемой конструкции значение **подчеркнутого отрицания,** обычно употребляется в следующих случаях:
1)      при наличии в предложении **частицы НИ или начинающихся с частицы НИ местоимения или наречия,** например: Да мы не имеем ни малейшего понятия о том, что делается с этими несчастными... (Л. Толстой); Никогда еще он не ощущал так горестно своей беззащитности, бессилия своего (Горький); До вас никто еще этого браслета не надевал (Куприн); ...Нисколько не облегчает процесса чтения (акад. Ф.Ф. Фортунатов);