# Односоставное или двусоставное?

Tags: синтаксис

*Для подтверждения права **не требуется обращения** в орган...*

Насколько с точки зрения русского языка легитимно в данном примере использование безличной структуры с родительным падежом дополнения?

Answer (score 4):

На мой взгляд, в этом случае употребление форм обоих падежей факультативно. Наш пример больше характерен для книжного стиля, поэтому родительный падеж вполне подойдет:

*Для подтверждения права не требуется (чего?) обращения в орган...*

Но здесь форма родительного падежа совпадает с формой именительного во мн. числе, а это вовсе не улучшает читабельность.

Вариант с винительным падежом будет более нейтральным по стилю:

*Для подтверждения права не требуется (что?) обращение в орган...*

Оба варианта мне кажутся правомерными, но второй - лучше.

Есть еще третий: заменить существительное *обращение* на инфинитив *обращаться*:

*Для подтверждения права не требуется (что делать?) обращаться в орган...*

Нагромождение отглагольных существительных существенно ухудшает читабельность, делает выражение более книжным. Поэтому есть смысл заменить существительное на глагол, если приоритетным является подход "чем проще - тем лучше".

Comment: "Вариант с винительным падежом будет более нейтральным по стилю: 
Для подтверждения права не требуется (что?) обращение в орган..."(inna)  
Здесь уже не винительный, а именительный.

Comment: Согласен с @inna по сути. Родительеый вполне правомерен.
Не согласен с тем, что это создаёт какие-то проблемы.
Более того, винительный здесь явно хуже, если вообще возможен. 
Если бы речь шла о каком-то конкретном обращении, еще можно было бы спорить. Но нут - вообше никакого не тремуется.

Answer (score 1):

Такое уже обсуждалось. Цитирую @olsa [из этого вопроса](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/5536/%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B8-%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-vs-%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B6):

> Речь идет, конечно, об отрицательных
>   конструкциях с существительными в
>   винительном и родительном падежах.
>   Почему-то в учебниках по РКИ этот
>   момент прекрасно разъяснен, а вот для
>   своих - ищи свищи. В связи с тем, что
>   подобные вопросы не единичны, считаю
>   нужным привести пространное пояснение
>   по данной теме.
>
> При переходных глаголах с
>   отрицательной частицей НЕ могут
>   употребляться существительные в
>   винительном и родительном падежах,
>   которые часто выступают как синонимы.
>   Винительный падеж обязателен: 1) в
>   конструкциях с частичным отрицанием:
>   Он не читает, а просматривает газеты;
>   2)в конструкциях со сложным
>   предикатом: я не смог купить тетрадь;
>   он не успел найти решение; он не
>   считал это занятие полезным; 3)в
>   устойчивых фразеологических
>   словосочетаниях: не морочь мне голову;
>   не заговаривай мне зубы.
>
> Винительный падеж предпочтительнее:
>   1)у существительных обозначающих
>   определенный конкретный предмет: Я не
>   купил книгу (о которой ты мне
>   говорил); Не потеряй билет на поезд;
>   2)у одушевленных предметов и имен
>   собственных: Я не видел тетю три года;
>   Он не любит Москву; 3)при наличии слов
>   некому, негде, не к чему: не к чему
>   приложить силы; негде опубликова
>   работу; 4)при наличии частиц с
>   отрицанием едва не, чуть не: едва не
>   уронил вазу, чуть не разбил тарелку.
>
> Родительный падеж обязателен: 1)в
>   устойчивых словосочетаниях: не играть
>   роли, не обращать внимания, не
>   придавать значения; 2)в сочетании с
>   глаголом не иметь: не иметь значения
>   (влияния, смысла, возможности, денег,
>   машины); 3)при наличии слов никакой,
>   ничей, а также частицы НИ: не получил
>   никакого подарка; не послал ни письма,
>   ни открытки; 4)в устойчивых
>   фразеологических сочетаниях: не
>   сводить глаз (с кого?); не находить
>   себе места; не сказать худого слова.
>
> Родительный падеж чаще употребляется:
>   1) у отвлеченных и абстрактных
>   существительных: не причинить
>   беспокойства (боли); не уронить
>   достоинства; не вынести трудностей; 2)
>   в сочетании с глаголами чувственного и
>   мысленного восприятия не видеть, не
>   слышать, не чувствовать, не замечать,
>   не понимать, не знать, не помнить и
>   драгими: не помнить адреса; не
>   замечать успеха.
>
> Что касается фразы "Я никогда не
>   изучал английский язык (английского
>   языка)", то здесь каких-то однозначных
>   рекомендаций нет. Следовательно, оба
>   варианта возможны.

Comment: А разве отрицательная частица НЕ не разрешает переходному глаголу строить управление с помощью родительного падежа?

Comment: Да, действительно есть что-то такое. Только я нюансы того правила, извините, забыл.

Comment: Исправил свой ответ.

Comment: Валентин, правило это известное, но очень громоздкое. Запомнить его очень трудно. Я в свое время запомнил последний его абзац, который Вы процитировали, и он мне помогал в большинстве случаев, если под рукой не было справочника, чтобы проверить правописание.